# Обращение к элементам класса из Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, формы

На данный момент присутствует класс Computers.cs с полями

```
public string name;
public int memory;
public double? price;
```

в классе конструкторы

```
public Computer(string name, int memory, double? price)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.memory = memory;
            this.price = price;
        }

public Computer()
        {
        }
```

И класс Data.cs для создания тестовой информации

```
private DataContext dataContext;
public void NewData()
        {
            Computers.Add(new Computer("Lenovo", 16, 40005)
            {
            });
            Computers.Add(new Computer("Dell", 8, 31250)
            {
            });
        }
dataContext.NewData();
```

Как из Windows Forms получить доступ к тестовой информации? Например, для поиска компьютера, который начинается с буквы D и записи этого значения в TextBox:

```
myTextBox.Text = dataContext.Computers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.StartsWith("D")).name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myTextBox.Text = dataContext.Computers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name.StartsWith("D")).name;
```

---

```
public class DataContext 
{
  ...

  public Computer ComputerByName(String start)
  {
    return Computers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name.StartsWith(start));
  }
}

myTextBox.Text = dataContext.ComputerByName("D").name;
```

Comment: действительно, была опечатка. но это же нарушение правил ООП?

Comment: @whyred_ Вам ООП или ехать?

Comment: ООП конечно же :)

Comment: @whyred_ Ну, сделайте для этого метод в `DataContext`,

Comment: @whyred_ который будет возвращать `Computer`.

Comment: не совсем понятно, как этот метод должен выглядеть